# Why forcing an event's subscribers to have a specific signature in C#?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

Declaring an event requires a delegate that the subscribers will follow (as far as I know):

```
public delegate void SomeEventHandler(object source, EventArgs args);
public event SomeEventHandler EventHappend;
```

But why do we need this delegate? Why don't let any method with any signature to subscribe to the event?

Comment: How would the sender of the event be able to determine the arguments?

Comment: Do you think of `public delegate void SomeEventHandler(int someInt, string someString, object someObject);` etc? Well, that's possible, just not so common.

Comment: @vc74 - Why would I want the sender to determine in arguments?

Comment: @BernhardHiller - I am thinking about any type of method. Not a specific uncommon one... Thanks both of you!

Comment: @Sipo, in order to call the event: if (EventHappend != null) { EventHappend(source, args); }, the caller has to know source and args for instance

Comment: @vc74 - but that is just because we defined it with a delegate with a `source` and `args`. But why not set a mechanism that support all kind of methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping your example...

```
class A
{
  public event EventHappend; // Invalid C# but let's pretend it could work

  public void DoSomething()
  {
    ...
    if (EventHappend != null)
    {
      // What should ??? be replaced with?
      EventHappend(???);
    }
  }
}

class B
{
  public B()
  {
    new A().EventHappend += EventHandler;
  }

  public void EventHandler(int anInt)
  ...
}

class C
{
  public C()
  {
    new A().EventHappend += EventHandler;
  }

  public void EventHandler(string aString)
  ...
}
```

What should ??? be replaced with to handle B and C's case (int or string in parameter)?

Comment: Thank you all. I chose this answer because it was the first, but all say the same thing in another way. Great answers, now I understand. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Because the caller expects to be able to pass a set of parameters to the callee. So both caller and callee need to agree on some sort of contract that defines the set of parameters the caller expects and the callee provides - which happens to be the delegate.

An "instance" of the delegate says nothing more than: Look here, here's a "pointer" to a method that conforms to my signature and by invoking me you can execute that method.

Example: The caller wants to pass its own instance, a `string` and an `int` to the callee. How would that work if the callee only accepted a `bool`?

One could have introduced the convention that *every* event handler needs to stick to the signature:

```
public void Method(object sender, EventArgs e);
```

so that the following event declaration syntax always works:

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> MyEvent;
```

But that would in many cases require you to create a class deriving from `EventArgs` if you want to pass any payload to the callee.

Answer (score 1):

> Why don't let any method with any signature to subscribe to the event?

Then how will the sender know what arguments to pass to the subscriber?

You may or may not know, this is how you raise the event that you declared in your question:

```
EventHappened(this, new EventArgs());
```

**Whenever you raise an event, you need to pass arguments to it!** Let's assume that you allowed any kind of method to subscribe to the event, then I will use this method to subscribe to `EventHappened`:

```
private void Foo(object sender, EventArgs e, int someNumber) {
    Console.WriteLine(someNumber);
}
```

When the event is raised, what will be printed? No one knows! The sender of the event did not pass an int argument!

You might say

> Then I'll just pass an extra int argument when I raise the event!

What if there is another method that also subscribes to the event, like this:

```
private void Bar(object sender, EventArgs e, List<string> myList) {
    Console.WriteLine(myList);
}
```

That way, your int argument is not compatible with a `List<string>`!

> "C# is not Javascript. You can't just pass 2 arguments to a method that needs 3" - Sweeper 2016

The delegate type is here to ensure that the sender of the event passes the right arguments and the subscriber is a method that can accept the passed arguments as parameters.

Comment: Really liked the "*C# is not Javascript. You can't just pass 2 arguments to a method that needs 3  - Sweeper 2016*" :) But since when you could pass two arguments to a method that need 3 in JS?!

Comment: Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fx107prd/1/ @Sipo

Comment: That is SO dangerous.